# Getting nextval from a backing sequence of an identity column

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I have a table column declared like this:

```
file_id number(10) generated always as identity primary key,
```

Is it possible to programatically get a `currval`/`nextval` from its backing sequence without actually looking into the SYS. tables to obtain the name of the sequence and then using `execute immediate` on that name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to programatically get a currval/nextval from its
>   backing sequence without actually looking into the SYS

Yes, if you really need to do so. You can simply look up that sequence name in the `USER_SEQUENCES` data dictionary view, or better yet `USER_TAB_IDENTITY_COLS` data dictionary view, and reference it in your query. Here is an example:

```
create table t1(
  c1 number  generated always as identity primary key
);

insert into t1 values(default);

select *  from t1;

C1
-----
    1
```

In my case, a sequence's name Oracle has created for the identity column is `ISEQ$$_92984`.

```
select "ISEQ$$_92984".nextval from dual;

NEXTVAL
-------
     2

insert into t1 values(default);

select * from t1;

 C1
 ---------
         1
         3
```

Comment: This is basically the same as looking into sys tables (since you need to first extract name of the sequence into a variable and then query the sequence by variable name), assuming I only know name of the table and column at the time of writing the plsql code. I was hoping for something simple, like TABLE.COLUMN.NEXTVAL :)